# SSH connection with Java using different port

Tags: java

How can I connect to an SSH server in Java using other than 22 port .
I just want to connect to the SSH server and run one command and then wait for 20-30 sec and run other command.

Comment: Are you using tomcat server?

Comment: How do you connect to port 22? Presumably the same library can do it for other ports as well. Must be a simple connection setting.

Comment: Depending on the library you are using there should be a method for setting the port (setPort) or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try [jcabi-ssh](http://ssh.jcabi.com), it is a very simple and convenient wrapper of JSch.

Let's say you want to connect to a Server on port 453, see below example :

```
import com.jcabi.ssh.Shell;
import com.jcabi.ssh.SSH;
Shell shell = new SSH("example.com", 453, "username", "key...");
```